# Use two external hard drive docks to retrieve data from RAID 0 disks

Tags: hard-drive, dock, external-disk, data-recovery, raid

Some while ago, I fried the power supply inside of my WD MyBook Pro Edition II, leaving the disks intact but rendering the enclosure itself totally useless. So now I have two 500GB 3.5" SATA drives, configured with RAID 0, that I want to retrieve the data from.

I already have one USB hard disk docking station. If I bought another one, and connected both of my drives to my Mac, would it somehow be possible for me to access the data on them?

Comment: If the data on there is worth it .. I'd be tempted to just buy a working MyBook off ebay and insert your disks into that.

Comment: Since WD external drive uses it's own RAID firmware this question is not Mac related. I would recommend you going to http://superuser.com/ with question like this.

Comment: @Speldosa Have you asked on superuser.com ? Would you please link to the question there?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - Apple's software RAID works so that once all the drives are present (or in the case of RAID mirroring - enough drives to ensure one copy of the data is present), you can then mount the RAID volume.

Unless you used a third party RAID driver in software or hardware, just getting the drives mounted should work.

Comment: So, in other words, it might not work if Wester Digital are using non standard RAID drivers for their MyBook drives?

Comment: Based on your comment and a re-read of the question, I think I misunderstood where the RAID controller lies. So - we might need to edit my answer into No - WD doesn't use Apple's Disk Utility to set up software RAID, so you'd need an additional software package or assistance from the vendor to recover the files. My guess is many people know how to do this, but sadly I've not had to solve that particular problem yet and can't guide you to success today on WD RAID.